# WebSphere MQ Windows client to Linux server user permissions

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, ibm-mq

How to manage client Windows users, connecting to a WebSphere MQ Server running on a Linux machine?
In other words, how to grant put and browse rights to Windows users for specific managers and queues, existing in a WebSphere MQ Server on a Linux machine?

This is my set up:

1. WebSphere MQ 7.5.0.2 Server running on a Linux machine
2. WebSphere MQ 7.5.0.2 client installed on a Windows machine

I am trying to connect to a queue but I get error **2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED in WMQ**, quite obviously since I didn't configure any user permissions for my Windows user.

I am using the IBM.XMS.dll on the client machine; and the default channel "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN".

I looked for information on the internet, but I am failing to find instructions for Windows - Linux set up. I would like to avoid disabling authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration and commands are same for all platforms. Following are some of the options available.

- Create the user ID on Linux and grant required authority.
- Set specific MCAUSER on the SVRCONN channel and grant the required authority
  for the MCAUSER. This is recommended only for SSL channels. Please check the
  following post for details on MCAUSER configuration.

  https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/all-the-ways-to-set-mcauser/
- Define CHLAUTH rule to map the client asserted user id to MCAUSER and grant
  required authorities to MCAUSER.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q013830_.htm?lang=en